# Convert just a hue into RGB

Tags: go, colors, rgb, hsv

What is the simplest way to convert a HSV colour into RGB, but where the Saturation and Value are **known** to be 100%?

I am programming in Go, but any algorithmic answer would do too. My hue value is `0.0 <= hue <= 1.0` raw, but conversion to degrees is trivial.

Example output:

```
hueToRGB(0.0)     =  (255, 0, 0)
hueToRGB(0.33333) =  (0, 255, 0)
hueToRGB(0.4)     =  (0, 255, 102)
```

Comment: The _simplest_ way is `func hueToRGB(_ float64) (byte, byte, byte) {return 255,0,0}`. You cannot go more simple. As this is not a question about Go: Why don't you take any of the algorithms?

Comment: I don't understand, that function simply returns a 100% red colour. I'm just looking for a colour conversion that can be simplified when knowing it is 100% intensity and 100% value (but with a differing hue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing the "HSV to RGB alternative" algorithm from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB_alternative), specialized to `s` = `v` = 1 gives this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func min3(a, b, c float64) float64 {
    return math.Min(math.Min(a, b), c)
}

func hueToRGB(h float64) (float64, float64, float64) {
    kr := math.Mod(5+h*6, 6)
    kg := math.Mod(3+h*6, 6)
    kb := math.Mod(1+h*6, 6)

    r := 1 - math.Max(min3(kr, 4-kr, 1), 0)
    g := 1 - math.Max(min3(kg, 4-kg, 1), 0)
    b := 1 - math.Max(min3(kb, 4-kb, 1), 0)

    return r, g, b
}

func main() {
    for h := 0.0; h < 1; h += 0.05 {
        r, g, b := hueToRGB(h)
        fmt.Println(h, r, g, b)
    }
}
```

This gives red, green and blue as `float64` in the range 0 to 1, but it should be easy to convert them to `uint8` if that's what you need.